# How to discover that a pendrive is in read-only mode?

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

My question is the following: I have a software in C++ running in a embedded Linux system, the software has a feature to export some data to a pendrive, now comes my pitfall, some users tried to use a old pendrive in a key to change between read/write and read-only mode. Now, I need to know how to check if the device is in read-only mode the show some feedback to the user in my application.
Is there a system call to check the read-only status before mount the device?

Comment: Try to write to it ..? Normally this "device is readonly" or "can't write file" message is displayed (e.g. is discovered) *when* the export/write attempt occurs. There are also other reasons why the write could fail .. in any case, I think there is a better chance to check read-only status *after* the filesystem is mounted.

Comment: What do you mean, "before mounting the device"? Is your application responsible for mounting the device? Why is that so?

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to handle this is to try to open a file for writing, then check whether `errno == EACCES`.

However, if you must check beforehand, that's

```
int on_readonly_fs(char const *path)
{
    struct statvfs fsinfo;

    while (statvfs(path, &fsinfo)) == -1)
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return -1;
    return fsinfo.f_flag & ST_RDONLY;
}
```

But this only works **after** mounting the device.

Comment: You can also parse `/proc/mounts` for an "ro" flag.  Or at a lower level if you know the device name containing the filesystem you can look in e.g. `/sys/class/block/sda1/` where you will find an `ro` file which contains a "1" if the device is read-only.